# Express - How to get data from POST form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to submit a form and save the data in database but I can't receive the data.

**My route is that:**

```
routes.post('/new-inventory/:dbname', inventory.store);
```

**My function in controller is that:**
I just do a console log to see if I receive the data. I know that is go to this function because show the first console.log . The `req.body` return `{}`.

```
store: (req, res) => {
    console.log('Storing new inventory...');
    console.log(req.body)
  },
```

**My form in html (jade) is that:**

```
div(class="popup-content")
  form(action="/new-inventory/#{dbname}" method="post")
    div(class="popup-title")
      span Novo inventário
    div(class="popup-data")
      div(class="form-group")
        label(for="inventory-description") Descrição
        input(type="text" id="inventory-description" value="#{description}" class="form-control" disabled)
      div(class="form-group")
        label Armazém
        select(class="form-control" id="wharehouse-select")
          each whare, i in wharehouse
            option(value="#{whare.szzstamp}" data-option="#{whare.armazem}") #{whare.armazem} - #{whare.zona}
      div(class="form-group")
        label(for="inventory-date") Data
        input(type="text" id="inventory-date" class="form-control")

    div(class="popup-button")
      div(class="btn-submit")

        button(type="submit") Criar
        div(class="close-btn")
          span Cancelar
```

In my node serve I start `body-parser`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // get information from html forms
```

How can I do this? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think you didn't add `name` attribute for each input field

Comment: Use name attr for inputs

Answer (score 2):

Just add `name` attribute in each input tag

Comment: It works but if I add name except in first input that is disabled. What is the solution for that? Thank you @Tlen

Comment: @user3242861 not sure if I understand, if the first input is disabled, you can get rid of its `name` or get rid of its data in body request.